# CakePHP - find request retrieving rows with 0 instead of 1

Tags: cakephp

I am in the process of migrating a CakePHP 1.3 app to 2.4.1 and while the process is painful, I have now reached something extremely weird.

When making a find to retrieve in the Testimonials table all rows which are active (ENUM column called activo with '0','1'), 1 being active and 0 being not active, Cake is retrieving only the row which is not active, 0.

```
$testimonials = $this->Testimonial->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Testimonial.activo' => '1')));

Rows:

ID name activo
1  James  1
2  Holly  0
3  David  1
```

Is retrieving Holly, instead of retreiving David and James. If make all of them inactive (0), it gets them all, but if I make them all active (1), it retrieves none at all. It's as if it decided that 0 is what I'm looking for instead of 1, when the condition I'm giving is 1.

Any clues as to what may be going on?

Edit: including generated SQL

```
SELECT `Testimonial`.`id`, `Testimonial`.`spa`, `Testimonial`.`eng`, `Testimonial`.`fre`, `Testimonial`.`ita`, `Testimonial`.`por`, `Testimonial`.`nombre`, `Testimonial`.`activo`, `Testimonial`.`created` FROM `database_dev`.`testimonials` AS `Testimonial` WHERE `Testimonial`.`activo` = 1
```

By the way, this is happening across all the finds I have found so far, in other tables where there is an activo field with ENUM and I'm calling for values of 1 or higher.

Tried several iterations for the find, like array('1'), '... >=' => '1', '...' => 1, etc.

Comment: can u show us the generated sql?

Comment: SELECT `Testimonial`.`id`, `Testimonial`.`spa`, `Testimonial`.`eng`, `Testimonial`.`fre`, `Testimonial`.`ita`, `Testimonial`.`por`, `Testimonial`.`nombre`, `Testimonial`.`activo`, `Testimonial`.`created` FROM `database_dev`.`testimonials` AS `Testimonial` WHERE `Testimonial`.`activo` = 1

Comment: Changing the type of column in the DB from ENUM to INT fixes the issue, but this will require me to change them in many tables plus change the values as INT will change the current values from 0 to 1 and 1 to 2, which is not ideal. Any suggestion as to how to fix ENUM will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the type of column in the DB from ENUM to INT fixes the issue.

But this will require me to change them in many tables plus change the values as INT will change the current values from 0 to 1 and 1 to 2, which is not ideal. Any suggestion as to how to fix ENUM will be greatly appreciated and changed to be the correct answer.

Comment: Or changing to varchar (for example) that will not change the values at all.

Answer (score 1):

If the activo column is ENUM, you should be using a string as the value you are using in your query.

```
array('Testimonial.activo' => '1'))
```

instead of

```
array('Testimonial.activo' => 1))
```

Comment: Aye, tried that (it was originally written as you put it) and several other iterations like array(1), '.. >=' => '1', etc. Will update the original post to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

use this
array('Testimonial.activo = "1"')